# How to get the value from jQuery UI selectable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui, html-lists

Hello I have created this list which changes the colour when you select an item using jQuery UI's selectable.

```
 <ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male1'>Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male2'>Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male3'>Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male4'>Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male5'>Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male6'>Item 6</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content" Name ='gender' value= 'male7'>Item 7</li>
    </ol>

<Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Select a Radio Button">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szNh3/2/

Ho do I send/get the selected item in a php file?

Comment: send/get when and what(a HTML-Element  may not be sended via HTTP)?...

Comment: I forgot to put the button in my example.. I  updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified segment from the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                // send an AJAX request to a PHP file
                $.get('myphpfile.php', {
                    selectedIndex: index
                }, function(data) {
                    // do stuff with the results from PHP
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

To do this from your button

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

    $("submit[name=Submit1]").click(function() {
        var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( $("#selectable") );
        $.get('myphpfile.php', {
            selectedIndex: index
        }, function(data) {
            // do stuff with the results from PHP
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I want to call the php file with the button and then send the answer of the li. Not when I click on this. I want to build a multiple choice test. And I do not want to use radio button as I want to change the colour of the whole row as in the example. thanks