# How to get values from Jquery UI Selectable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a question regarding the Jquery US Selectable I have already looked at this post and I still cant figure out the problem: [How to get the value from jQuery UI selectable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618319/how-to-get-the-value-from-jquery-ui-selectable-in-php)
I would like to get all the values I selected from the list (not the indexes but the values!!) into a array and than send it to PHP (via POST method).
I have prepared a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aqearvzL/)

I have to select the values and not the indexes.
Example of the list:

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='1'>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='2'>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='3'>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='4'>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='5'>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='6'>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value='7'>Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

From this list I have to select the values. The code below only gets the index of the list. I would like to know how to select the values and send the values to the same file ('index.php'). Than if the array is set I can afterwards manipulate with the data.

```
$( function() {
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
  stop: function() {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
      result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance. I'd really like to know how to get the values to an array and send it to the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element reference from `this` inside the stop function. Based on that, you can access the `value` attribute using `.attr()` . Example:

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    stop: function() {
      var result = $("#select-result").empty();
      $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
        result.append(" #" + ($(this).attr("value")));//$(this).attr("value")
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/2068/

You can use the result's value in whatever way you want. You can use `ajax` to pass these to the PHP backend

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {

    // this works for me
    result.append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
```

I hope that works out :-)